# PHP login page only accessible to user that logged in?

Tags: php

Been looking at several of these and haven't found any luck - i'm sure it's something simple i'm doing.  I have a basic HTML login page, that calls login.php.

HTML:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <div align="center">Username: 
        <input type="text" name="uname">
        <br><br>
        Password: 
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="login" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

LOGIN.PHP:

```
<?php

require ('sql_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username=mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
if (!$_POST['uname'] | !$_POST['pass'])
 {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('You did not complete all of the required fields')
        window.location.href='htmlogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
     }
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$url=$row['defaultpage'];

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
        header($url);
exit();
}
else{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
}
else{
}
?>
```

I have got the form sucesfully connecting to the DB and will let me login (i've got it setup with a database entry so its redirecting to a specific URL based on who logs in.)

My question is, I do not want that specific URL accessable to someone who has not logged in.  I've tried a couple different options, using `session_start();` but apparently i'm either not entering the correct information, or doing it on the correct pages.  Here is what I currently have on the landing page that a specific user would be sent to after logging in:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location:http://mywebsite.com/htmllogin.html")
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My thought was that in the landing page, if it doesn't match the session it would re-direct the user to the original html login page.
 Any help...thanks!

Comment: Is this second code block your login.php file?  Where do you set your username key in $_SESSION?

Comment: You have a fatal error in your php. You should add a `;` behind the header() function.

Comment: Are you sure you set the session variable 'username'?

Comment: i didn't explain it very well...the HTML page is called htmllogin.html.  it calls the login.php, then the database forwards it to my landing page which is user specific based on who logs in.

Comment: I edited the post and included my login.php.  Thanks.

Comment: You're never setting your $_SESSION variable.

Comment: ok, thanks @arkoElsenaar, i've added the semi-colon, now when logging in it just refreshes the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Once your user is verified and should be logged in, you need to create your $_SESSION variables.

```
<?php
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['uname'];
?>
```

The above piece of code should be placed inside the next if-structure in login.php:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['uname'];
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!')
        window.location.href='htmllogin.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
        header($url);
exit();
}
```

Comment: So this needs to replace the php code I have on my landing page?

Comment: No, once you know your user logged in correctly, you have to add this piece of code to your login.php page.

Comment: ok, - i've added all of this, but instantly get a server 500 error, no matter what I input into the username/password field